# Why don't battery manufacturers make 5 V batteries?

Tags: batteries

Why is it so? Is there something that cannot be crossed while manufacturing 5 V batteries? They can make billions though! Still...

Comment: the voltage of a cell is to do with its chemistry - that's the starting point.

Comment: Why exactly would they make billions?

Comment: Isn't that just a USB power bank?

Comment: Like Jim said, chemistry. But manufacturers did the next best thing. They made battery banks which use electronic circuitry so that they can be charged at 5V, and also supply power at 5V. And you are right. They did make billions.

Comment: Good question a, a better one would be why did manufacturers make logic to run at 3 or 5V.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They don't have a choice

The voltage of a battery is decided [by the reactants in the battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_cell).

There are only so many viable battery chemistries out there.   You can't just pick two random chemicals off [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)); it also has to be possible/practical --

- To actually build it.
- At a competitive price-point.
- Out of readily available materials.
- Which are relatively non-toxic.
- And don't weigh too much.
- Endure many recharge cycles (if it's secondary).
- Never explode.
- Have enough storage capacity to bother.
- and not hopelessly lag behind other successful batteries in any category.

These restrictions soon winnow the thousands of combinations down to just a few, and none of them have a 5V or 2.5V output.

Answer (score 4):

The output voltage of a battery varies while charging and discharging, but most devices that run on 5V need a relatively constant voltage (eg. USB is 5V +- 0.25V). Therefore a voltage regulator is often required *anyway*, to convert the varying battery voltage to a constant system voltage.

Regulators are generally designed to either reduce the voltage (linear regulator or 'buck' converter) or increase it ('boost' converter), so ideally the battery voltage should be above or below the required system voltage.

Battery powered USB devices often use a single Lipo cell that charges to 4.2V and puts out ~4.2-3.5V. This is ideal because it can be charged from USB with a simple linear regulator, and (if necessary) produce 5V with a boost converter.

Comment: ... and today typical applications use 3.3V at most, which is equally easy to generate from 4.2-3.5V input.

Comment: @asdfex - actually it's not necessarily trivial to generate 3.3v over the full range of a single lithium cell, because pulse-load brownout towards the end of discharge can run into regulator dropout overhead.  However many "3.3v" parts will run quite happily and in-spec with a 3v or even 2.7v regulator, which can provide more margin.  And one useful aspect of the otherwise aging ATmega line is that at an appropriate clock they can run over the full range of cell voltage without a regulator, which is especially good for simple circuits that sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, four Ni-Cd cells in series will produce approximately 5 volts.

Comment: I agree, the smaller unit cells can always be composed into larger batteries and it gives users the ability to make the larger voltages by place the individual cells in serial. Meanwhile if you only had 5V or 6V or whatever you couldn't get smaller voltages at all.